# ADO.NET Entities - Model-first data annotations

Tags: model-view-controller, ado.net, annotations, entities

I'm using the approach explained here:-

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/06/ef-feature-ctp5-code-first-walkthrough.aspx

I'd like to use the surface designer to develop my model, then use partial classes to include data annotations for validation.  However, if I use a partial class and then attempt to reference an existing property the compiler complains that the property already exists.

How do I get over this?

---

e.g.

```
public partial class Product
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The compiler says "Name is already defined".

Comment: How are you referencing the property? Can you post your code?

Answer (score 3):

I just ran across the same problem on how to annotate an entity class that is generated from the Entity Data Model and I found the answer on another stackoverflow thread:

[Using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations with Entity Framework 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915957/using-system-componentmodel-dataannotations-with-entity-framework-4-0/)