# Is this still the way to handle JSON serializer circular reference exception in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm using MVC5 and Visual Studio 2013 with entity framework. Basic problem is when we have a many-to-many relationships like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }

    public Patient()
    {
        Groups = new HashSet<Group>();
    }
}
public class Group
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Person> People{ get; set; }

    public Group()
    {
        People = new HashSet<Person>();
    }
}
```

and we want to get the JSON representation for a record like this

```
 Person person = db.People.Include(x => x.Groups).Where(i => i.ID == id).Single();
string json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
```

the JsonConvert throws a circular reference exception.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769200/serialize-one-to-many-relationships-in-json-net) has an easy solution by configuring it to ignore circular reference exceptions:

```
var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects };
string json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person,serializerSettings);
```

My question is this: is this still the best way to deal with this situation? Those SO answers are now very old, and this seems like a very common situation. I've updated everything I can think of to update in my solution, but I still get the exception unless I do the extra configuration step.

Also, are there side effects to setting `PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects`? Is there any reason ever not do this?

Answer (score 0):

using datamembers is a better solution I think.
Here you can chose what to serialize and what not.

Not adding attributes to the unwanted/circular references solves the problem of the circular serialization.

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DataContractAndDataMember.htm

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to avoid eager loading, by removing include extension method from your statement. Or create another custom class for your dependent object and use projection using select(x => new CustomClass {PropertyOne = p.PropertyOne})

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add
`[ScriptIgnore(ApplyToOverrides = true)]` into your text template (.tt) file (part of the EF data model).

Here a portion of my text template before

```
#>
<#=codeStringGenerator.NavigationProperty(navigationProperty)#>
<#
```

Once I inserted the code the line above the `codeStringGenerator` my classes auto generated and looked like this:

```
[ScriptIgnore(ApplyToOverrides = true)]
public virtual ICollection<Currency> Currencies { get; set; }
```

I also needed to modify the `UsingDirectives` function to insert `"using System.Web.Script.Serialization;"`