# How to deserialize json class containing a nesting of the same class (Unity C#)?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, unity-game-engine, json.net

I have a class `Person.cs` which needs to store a list of Friends (List of `Person.cs`).  However, it would be overkill to store the whole Person information in that array, just to have a complete object.

**Json file**

```
[ 
    { 
        "Username": "mary",    
        "DisplayName": "Mary Sanchez",
        "Age": 20,
        "Friends": [
            {"Username": "jonathan"},
            {"Username": "katy"}
        ]
    }, 
    { 
        "Username": "jonathan",
        "Age": 25,
        "DisplayName": "Jonathan White",    
        "Friends": [
            {"Username": "mary"},
            {"Username": "katy"}
        ]
    },
    { 
        "Username": "katy",   
        "DisplayName": "Katy Rivers", 
        "Age": 28,
        "Friends": [
            {"Username": "mary"},
            {"Username": "jonathan"}
        ]
    }
]
```

**C# class**

```
public class Person

{
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public List<Person> Friends { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see the Property `Friends` is an array of `Person`. It would be overkill for me to redefine all the persons in the array of friends of the json file, especially if it's a large file.  I can't instantiate 'mary', because her friends 'jonathan' and 'katy' appear later in the json file. As you see this becomes a nesting dependency problem. **Also assume this file has a lot of circular references as everyone is friends with each other.**

The problem is ofcourse that I will end up with incomplete Person object in the array of `Friends`. If I want to retrieve mary's friends ages, it will result in null values:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("Assets/Resources/Json/persons.json");
Persons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(reader.ReadToEnd());
Person mary = Persons.Find(i => i.Username == "mary");
foreach(Person friend in mary.friends){
    int age = friend.Age; //this will be null
}
```

So I tried to fix it by looping through the list again and manually retrieving the friend variable:

```
foreach (Person friend in mary.Friends)
{
    Person friend = PersonManager.Persons.Find(i => i.Username == profile.Username);
    int age = friend.age;
}
```

This works, but is very inefficient though. Especially if I have more properties that are like the `Friends` property. Mind you, the `Persons` array is in a separate class and I had to make the list static in order to retrieve it all times (i believe this is bad practice too). Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve in one go?

Comment: What code serializes the object-graph? If that code uses Newtonsoft too then use its built-in object-reference setting.

Comment: Map your person to some PersonVM or PersonDto and then deserialize. Your VM or DTO should contain only properties what you need

Comment: Guys thanks for your suggestions! I was missing double quotes somewhere, so now the json is ok again. And I researched DTO's , that is indeed what I need to implement!

Comment: I deleted my answer because I found numerous errors in it, including one you pointed out. I’ll repost a better solution in the morning.

Comment: @Dai No problem, take your time! I did understand the basics and I'll wait patiently.

Comment: @IT-Girl The correct solution (which does not support full PersonDtos in the Friends lists) would work like this: 1) deserialise to List<PersonDto>. 2) Loop through and convert them all to Person instances without yet populating the Friends list. 3) Create the dictionary from the List<Person> instead of List<PersonDto>. 4) In a second pass populate the `List<Person>[i].Friends` lists (using the dictionary for O(1) lookup) using  the Friends list from the corresponding `List<PersonDto>[i].Friends` list.

Comment: [`PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm#PreserveReferencesHandling) may do what you need, it adds an `"$id"` to an object the first time it is serialized, and serializes it with a `"$ref"` when subsequently encountered.  See: [Serialize one to many relationships in Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5769200/3744182) and [JSON.NET Error Self referencing loop detected for type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7397207/3744182).

Comment: And, to force all `Person` objects to be stored with references preserved, apply `[JsonObject(IsReference = true)]` to `Person`.  Demo fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/aAKLgi.  Note however that Json.NET always fully serializes the **first** occurrence of a given `Person` in the serialization graph, not the **topmost** occurrence.  This is because it's a single-pass serializer.  In your question, you fully serialize the topmost occurrences.  If you want that you cannot use `PreserveReferencesHandling` and will need to preprocess and postprocess your data model instead.

Comment: The list of Person in Person is recursive and will probably cause bottomless serialization issue. A has B that has C that has A that has B.... you should store a list of person id and a dictionary of Person by id for fetching them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Btw, your JSON is invalid. You'll need to look at "Jonathan", see how the record has two `UserName` properties and no `DisplayName`. I assume the second occurrence should be named `DisplayName`.

---

The quick-and-easy solution is [to use `PreserveReferencesHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_PreserveReferencesHandling.htm), but this also needs to be used by the code that generates the JSON in the first place. If you have no control over the JSON being generated *and* you want to keep on using Json.NET (aka `Newtonsoft.Json`)  then you'll need to define a separate DTO type (do *not* use class inheritance to avoid copying+pasting properties between your DTO type and your business/domain entity type, that's not what inheritance is for - if you're concerned about tedium then use T4 to generate `partial` types from a shared list of properties).

So **add** these classes:

```
public class PersonDto
{
    public string          UserName    { get; set; }
    public string          DisplayName { get; set; }
    public int             Age         { get; set; }
    public List<PersonRef> Friends     { get; set; }
}

public class PersonRef
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Then change your deserialization code to this:

```
public List<Person> GetPeople( String jsonText )
{
    List<PersonDto> peopleDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< List<PersonDto> >( jsonText );

    List<Person> people = peopleDto
        .Select( p => ToPersonWithoutFriends( p ) )
        .ToList();

    Dictionary<String,PersonDto> peopleDtoByUserName = peopleDto.ToDictionary( pd => pd.UserName );

    Dictionary<String,Person> peopleByUserName = people.ToDictionary( p => p.UserName );

    foreach( Person p in people )
    {
        PersonDto pd = peopleDtoByUserName[ p.UserName ];
        
        p.Friends.AddRange(
            pd.Friends.Select( pr => peopleByUserName[ pr.UserName ] )
        );
    }

    return people;
}

private static Person ToPersonWithoutFriends( PersonDto dto )
{
    return new Person()
    {
         UserName    = dto.UserName,
         DisplayName = dto.DisplayName,
         Age         = dto.Age,
         Friends     = new List<Person>()
    };
}
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks! I am nearly there, however it's giving me "Cannot implicitly convert type List<PersonDto>' to 'List<Person>", because Friends in Profile.cs is a List<Person> while peopleByUserName is PersonDto.  Any idea what I can do to fix this?

Comment: @IT-Girl I was wrong about being able to inline `ToPerson`. I’ve updated my answer.

Comment: @IT-Girl I've restored my answer now with the changes.