# add data annotations programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I am working on an asp mvc3 app that is using **.NET 4**.

However the model I want to use is in a class library that is using **.NET 3.5** and cannot change.

Can I add the **.NET 4** *data annotations* to some properties in my model in the controller programatically to get some easy validation?

Comment: I wonder if you can create a new class that inherits from the one in the library, then override the appropriate properties and add annotations in your version. If the library utilizes this class internally a bunch, this might not be possible, even if it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own ModelMetadataProvider and this should do want you want

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=715

Answer (score 2):

Interesting, I never try that before but could you declare a partial class in your .NET 4 project and use **MetadataTypeAttribute** to create a sibling class that hold the metadata and decorate it with validation.

Never try that before but similar approach is used in ASP.NET MVC (only for Silverlight). you could see [Using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations with Entity Framework 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915957/using-system-componentmodel-dataannotations-with-entity-framework-4-0/)