# Replacement for [Display] Attribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Given the class:

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Observation { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Done { get; set; }
}
```

I know i can define my [Key] Attribute and other mapping settings by create a mapping class in another project and inheriting from EntityTypeConfiguration.

but how can i replace the [display] attribute so i don't have to add a reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations to my common dll?

tell me if i'm not clear enough

Comment: There is nothing wrong with referencing DataAnnotations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [add data annotations programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394564/add-data-annotations-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own attribute, then write a class that inherits `AssociatedMetadataProvider` and reads data from your attribute into a `ModelMetadata` instance.

Your class would be similar or identical to the [built-in version](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/df47d044190b#src%2fSystem.Web.Mvc%2fDataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider.cs).