# Data Annotations for validate an entity framework entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I used EF to create an entity.

Now The user can input datas to the DB trough entity framework.

I want to validate the object by using Data Annotations.

The solution should be to create one object that inherits of all the EF methods and validate the field.

So Do I have to redeclare all fields in the child class? or DO I have to redeclare the only class I want to validate?

Thanks for helping me, I'm new in c# .net workd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Duplicate post to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915957/using-system-componentmodel-dataannotations-with-entity-framework-4-0/)

Philosophy : make a partial class and set the data annotations to another class