# How to hide primary key input field using editorfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

Hi I'm using Editorfor() to make a little form that submits view model to the controller.  Editorfor() nicely prints input fields of the model but it also prints primary key field. So I want to hide primary key field.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.viewmodel)
```

this is markup that I have.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.viewmodel.Id);
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.viewmodel)
```

have tried this but does not work. and I wanted to make an approach directly to the model but I'm using EF Designer, so I'm not sure where to begin. Please give me an advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
public int ProductID { get; set;
```

Comment: How to do the same thing with the EF Designer?

Comment: look here(bottom part) http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs

Comment: Or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915957/using-system-componentmodel-dataannotations-with-entity-framework-4-0/

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom editor template. For example:

**MyViewModel.cshtml** (stored in ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates folder, structured like a partial view):

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Property1)
@Html.TextboxFor(m => m.Property2)
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Property3)
// Whatever else you want in the template
```

Then you can just call EditorFor on your model in your view that needs to use it and MVC will know to use your custom template:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyViewModel)
```

To use a custom display template that isn't based on the name of the type, you can also use the `[UIHint]` attribute as described here: http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't create any field for your key attribute. Without a field to check, the validation has nothing to complain about. Later you can supply a value for the primary key in the controller.